# Samba reports incorrect disk space when on shared mount points not directly beneath /media

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount, network-shares, samba

I have some shares that are located on mount points like:

```
media/
  backups/
    01/
    02/
    03/
    ...
```

01, 02, 03 and so on are different physical drives mounted at those locations for organizational purposes.

This seems to cause samba to report the available space of the root drive for these volumes and not the drive on the mount point.

The problem is that when these shares are accessed from a network client, that client cannot copy a set of files to the share the exceed the space of the root drive, despite having plenty of space on the actual target disk on the mount point.

*As a side note, a functional workaround for Windows is to use TeraCopy, which allows you to ignore disk space warnings*

Is there a configuration I can set or anything I can do to have samba report the disk space correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You can use "dfree command" in "global" section of smb.conf, like this:

```
dfree command = /usr/local/samba/bin/dfree
```

when "dfree" is a simple script, for example:

```
#!/bin/sh
df  $1 | tail -1 | awk '{print $2" "$4}'
```

Reference: [dfree command (S)](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem also and I think the correct solution is to create a new samba share for each physical drive.  When listed as a separate share, it correctly reports the size of the physical drive.