# How to make samba share show free space correctly?

Tags: hard-drive, debian, samba, proxmox

I have a server with proxmox on it, that has 2 VMs running.
One of these servers has a samba share that is accessed by the other. The share points to the mounting point of a drive.

And here comes the problem: the drive was at first 1.5 Tb, now it's 1.8 Tb, after allocating more space to it in proxmox. On the "host" side, it shows up perfectly, but on the client side, samba shows that it's still 1.5 Tb.

[Picture from the host side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qyjjd.png)
[Picture from the client side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rslag.png)

I resized the partition using fdisk I think.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does it update if you unmount and remount the share on the client? Or if you reboot the client? You may need to set `dfree command` in `smb.conf` per https://superuser.com/a/1467387/673426

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem! As you can see on the host side, `df -h` shows that it's still 1.5 Tb, although I assigned more room to the volume, the filesystem didn't get that. As this is ext4, I used `sudo resize2fs [volume]`.